# how to call a second activity without a button click in android studio

Tags: android-studio

I want to display winner's name as a second activity when an if condition satisfied in activity one

```
if(scorep1==50)
{  
  Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,PlayerOneWin.class);
  Mainactivity.this.startActivity(intent1);
}
```

App crashes when this condition reaches
please answer

Comment: code looks fine. please also post the crash log

Answer (score 0):

Check the Logcat (bottom right in android studio) while the app is running, to know exactly where the app is crashing.
Code looks fine and you don't need to do `MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent1);` you can just do `startActivity(intent1);`